# How to add @SerialVersionUID to an anonymous class?

Tags: java, serialization, scala, programming-languages, anonymous-class

I want to translate the following piece of code from Java to Scala:

```
Foo foo = new Foo() { private static final long serialVersionUID = 12345L; }
```

Class `Foo` is an abstract class.

How does the equivalent code look like in Scala?

Comment: How are the title and the actual question related?

Comment: Well, I ask in the title how I can add `@SerialVersionUID` to a anonymous class and show an example of a constructed anonymous class with a `serialVersionUID`, which exhibits said question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [Scala annotation for adding the ID](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.3/scala/SerialVersionUID.html). But it seems, that you cannot apply this solution to anonymous inner classes. However, according to the [Scala FAQ](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/259):

> In Scala private values that evaluate
>   to a constant known at compile-time
>   are turned into private static final
>   Java variables. This undocumented
>   feature should do the trick for you.
>   Just check out the implementation of
>   lists in Scala (see e.g.
>   src/scala/List.java). Both classes ::
>   and Nil have a field serialVersionUID
>   of the following form: 
>   private val serialVersionUID = numeric literal;

The code

```
object Ser extends Application {
    trait Foo { def xy: Int }
    val x = new Foo with java.io.Serializable { def xy = 2; private val serialVersionUID = 1L }
}
```

compiles fine with the 2.8.1 compiler. I haven't tested it, though as to whether the serial version of the resulting class is actually the one supplied.

Comment: Mhh, but this would add it as instance method and not as a class method, right? I don't think that will work ...

Comment: @soc: See the excerpt from the FAQ: "In Scala private values that evaluate to a constant known at compile-time are turned into private static final Java variables."

Comment: WTH? I didn't know that and never assumed this would happen ... Thanks a lot! I just wonder if that is all what's needed or if there is some special magic necessary regarding serialVersionUID ...

Comment: @soc: I don't know, but I assume, that it is more general than that: why make an instance variable (or: magic getter or whatsoever) for something known already at compile time to be constant and shared with the same value across all instances of a class?